# NodeJS: Native c++ module with multi-threading (openmp)

Tags: c++, node.js, windows, multithreading, openmp

I have a very basic native module for NodeJS which essentially wraps a more complicated c++ program which includes multithreading using OpenMP (it's a Monte Carlo simulation).  This c++ program works fine on its own and when called from python using a cython module to wrap the c++ code.  However, when I compile it to a native node module (using /OpenMP as the parameter to the MSBuild compiler) it only uses one thread.

The following is my binding.gyp for reference:

```
{  "targets": [
{
  "target_name": "LossForecast",
  "sources": [ "NodeLossForecast.cpp", "src/AutoDiff.cpp" ],
  "include_dirs":["src", "<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")"],
  'conditions': [
    ['OS=="win"', 
      {
        'cflags': ["/EHsc", "/O2", "/openmp"]
      }
    ]
  ]
}  ]}
```

Answer (score 3):

So, I am writing down my files for running a simple [node-addon-api](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api) pi program using OpenMP. Although [node-addon-api](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api) is experimental, it will be soon released as an official api for node.js. Its very simple.

This is for Windows only. And I can confirm if it is running in multiple processors.

**binding.gyp**

```
{
    "targets": [
        {
            "target_name": "nodeOpenMP",
            "defines": [
                "VERSION=0.0.1",
                "NAPI_DISABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS"
            ],
            "sources": [
                "module.cc"
            ],
            "include_dirs": [
                "<!(echo %cd%/node_modules/node-addon-api)"               
            ],
            "conditions": [
                [
                    'OS=="win"',
                    {
                        'msvs_settings': {
                            'VCCLCompilerTool' : {
                                'AdditionalOptions' : ['/MT','/openmp']
                            }
                         }
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You have to add `VCCLCompilerTool` and then under `AdditionalOptions` add `/openmp' as mentioned above.

Here's a simple PI program that I wrote,

**module.cc**

```
#include <napi.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>    // for GetCurrentProcessorNumber()

int getThreads(){
    // Get number of threads
    omp_set_num_threads(3);
    int n = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel reduction(+:n)
        n += 1;
    return n;
}

double GetPi(short numOfThreads,long numberOfSteps){
    long i;
    double pi, sum = 0.0;
    double step = 1.0/(double) numberOfSteps;

    omp_set_num_threads(numOfThreads);

    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        std::cout << "This thread is running on processor: " << GetCurrentProcessorNumber() << "\n";
        double x;
        #pragma omp for reduction(+:sum) 
            for(i = 0; i < numberOfSteps; i++) {
                x = ( i + 0.5 ) * step;
                sum += 4.0 / (1 + x*x);
            } 
    }

    std::cout << "Total no. of threads (not processors)" <<getThreads() << std::endl;
    pi =  step * (double)sum;
    return pi;
}

Napi::Value calculatePi(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info ){
     Napi::Env env = info.Env();

    // check for no. of arguments
    if(info.Length()<2){
        Napi::TypeError::New(env, "Wrong number of arguments").ThrowAsJavaScriptException();
        return env.Null();
    }

    if (!info[0].IsNumber() || !info[1].IsNumber()) {
        Napi::TypeError::New(env, "Wrong arguments").ThrowAsJavaScriptException();
        return env.Null();
    }

    double numThreads = info[0].As<Napi::Number>().DoubleValue();
    double numSteps = info[1].As<Napi::Number>().DoubleValue();

    double pi = GetPi(numThreads, numSteps);

    Napi::Number PI = Napi::Number::New(env, pi);

    return PI;
}

Napi::Object Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports){
    // register the functions that are to be exported    
    exports.Set(Napi::String::New(env, "pi"), Napi::Function::New(env, calculatePi));
    return exports;
}

NODE_API_MODULE(nodeOpenMP, Init);
```

**testOMP.js**

```
const omp = require("./build/Release/nodeOpenMP");
const numThreads = 4, numSteps = 1000000;
console.log( numThreads, numSteps );
```

Simply copy paste the files above accordingly. Don't forget to install `node-addon-api`(locally) and `node-gyp`(globally) and then run:

`node-gyp configure build && node --no-warnings testOMP.js`

You should get an output like this:

```
This thread is running on processor: 3
This thread is running on processor: 3
This thread is running on processor: 0
This thread is running on processor: 3
Total no. of threads (not processors): 3
```

I am thinking of soon making a cross-platform npm package `node-openmp`.

Follow this repo and contribute. I am open to any contributions.
[Himujjal/node-openmp](https://github.com/Himujjal/node-openmp)